# Is there a name for this kind of variable stomping bug?

Tags: python, changelog

I solved a bug recently where (in Python code) a dictionary variable was initialized outside the loop, then modified and assigned to another dictionary within the loop. The expectation was that a deep copy of the variable was being assigned to the dictionary, but really it was the same variable being passed in over and over. The end result was that the dictionary contained a bunch of repeated dictionaries within it, instead of unique dictionaries for each iteration of the loop.

Something like this:

```
d = []
a = {"key": "value"}
for x in range(5):
    a["key2"] = "value" + str(x)
    d.append({"results": a})
```

Where the proper behavior is something more like this

```
d = []
for x in range(5):
    a = {"key": "value", "key2": "value" + str(x)}
    d.append({"results": a})
```

Going to write a changelog message for this fix, I was wondering if there was a proper term for this kind of bug? The best I could come up with was "variable stomping" but I believe there's more descriptive.

Comment: “Replace shallow copy with deep copy”?

Comment: The error wasn't that the *variable* was itself stomped, it's that the variable pointed to the wrong thing (a single dictionary that was never copied), causing the data in that dictionary to get stomped.  I'd call it a "pointer error" but that's me showing my age; the term "pointer" doesn't actually have meaning in Python.  "Reference error"?  "Shallow copy error"?  "Data overwriting error"?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a line like

> Create a new dictionary at each iteration to prevent mutating template

This makes it clear what the original issue is and how it's solved - as for naming, the word is *mutating*!

Comment: @KellyBundy I just reverted it - please feel free to suggest an edit!

Comment: I removed it because it confuses me. Who are they quoting, what's the source and context?

Comment: speculating, it sounds like they're just looking to make a `git` or other VCS commit